# parent transaction id in refund in authorize.net

Tags: php, authorize.net, silent-post, authorize.net-aim

I'm using Authorize.net AIM and silent post.
The purchase is done via AIM, and it's working fine.
If the user wants to refund then it's tracked via silent post url.
But there is no parent transaction id for a refund transaction.
So I couldn't understand of which transaction the refund is for.
Do anyone have any idea on this one? Or how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep Test mode turned off, then you will get a Transaction ID for each payment transaction. For a refund call (credit or void) pass the particular transaction id which can identify the payment. In test mode Authorize.net returns 0 as transaction id. For more [Test refunds on Authorize.net using a test account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258793/test-refunds-on-authorize-net-using-a-test-account)

Comment: this example isn't working for getting the transaction details http://developer.authorize.net/api/transaction_details/

Comment: never mind, I forgot to enable Transaction Details API from the panel

Comment: @gins thomas Can I get customer profile id using the transaction id